# What is the status on webminers?

Tags: cpu-mining, project, webminer

Are there any ongoing projects trying to develop a widely accessible WebCL-powered mining software? I've heard of two in the past, but their websites don't seem to be working any more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So let me summarize all the other answers:

[Krad Miner](http://kradminer.com) used to be the first WebCL miner, but due to DDOS attacks it was not working for awhile. Later it was bought and open sourced as [Tumen Miner](https://github.com/temujin9/tumen_miner).

[BitMinter](http://bitminter.com/) allows you to mine on their pool with OpenCL miner through Java Webstart.

[www.coined.com](http://www.coined.com) has undefined status, WOT reports it as an abusive site.

[WebCL bitcoin miner](http://webcl.nokiaresearch.com/jsoclbm/) looks like a fully functional WebCL miner

[Bitcoin Plus](http://www.bitcoinplus.com/) allows one to mine through a Java Applet, but it is a (highly inefficient) CPU miner.

And there are a couple other less notable web CPU miners.

Comment: bitcoin plus uses Java Applet for mining, not Javascript.

Comment: @otakun85 Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

While not directly a WebCL miner there is a miner which uses OpenCL via  Java Webstart so is accessible to any internet user with Java installed and apropriate hardware.

http://www.BitMinter.com

The site is both a pool and a custom java miner. 
The pool can be used with other miners however the BitMinter miner works only with the BitMinter pool.

Answer (score 3):

There is a page claiming to be an OpenCL miner at [coined.com](http://www.coined.com) but I'm not sure if it's functional or not.

Answer (score 3):

Would http://webcl.nokiaresearch.com/jsoclbm/ meet your needs?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a current option for adding mining to your website: https://coinhive.com/