# Are there any Bitcoin miners that run from a web page and use the GPU?

Tags: gpu, webminer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the status on webminers?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/what-is-the-status-on-webminers)

I love Bitcoin mining so far.

However, I need to do it without running a Java applet that I download {see BitMinter for an example of this} and without downloading a program.

Are there any Bitcoin miners that run from a web page and use the GPU? [I couldn't find any.](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=online%20GPU%20bitcoin%20miners)

Ideally, something similar to http://www.bitcoinplus.com/ but using the GPU with/instead of the CPU.

Answer (score 3):

The rather new WebCL technology enables this, unfortunately WebCL is not directly supported by browsers yet.

See http://www.coined.com/ 
and http://webcl.nokiaresearch.com/jsoclbm/ for examples of such miners. I expect more will follow in the coming months.

Comment: I tried to download it and Firefox 4 {it doesn't work with the latest Firefox.} After going to coined.com and running it, all I get is a CPU spike and then a decrease to 0 around a second later. I have installed the OpenCL SDK from both Intel and AMD; I tried one of them; they showed up but I didn't see anything happen besides the spike. BTW, what numbers should I put in the boxes? I tried random combinations for one and a few educated guesses for some others.