# Is there a mining software that I can run on my webspace (php, ruby, python)?

Tags: cpu-mining, webminer

Is there a miner written to be run on webspace, e.g. in ruby, php or python?

I know, it will be to slow and its not worth it, but I want to see it though :)

Comment: If you are thinking of doing this on a hosted system, know that all hosting companies are aware of bitcoin mining and starting long ago specifically will look for high cpu usage and kill of those instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look into webminers - [What is the status on webminers?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/what-is-the-status-on-webminers)

But generally, it's not really worth it. Unless you get a lot of high-end-graphic-card-owning users to stay on your website for a long while, you won't earn much. You can try running some of the webminers on your own machine and see how much you can earn for example by using my [Mining Calculator](http://tpbitcalc.appspot.com/). Having someone with a 100MHash/s graphic card (fairly decent for a non-dedicated miner) on for 24 hours would give you about a cent of revenue.

All in all, you're probably better off with adding some ads to your website.

Comment: @Erik was asking about server-side miners, not client-side miners.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a python-only miner.  Not sure if it still functions:

- https://github.com/jgarzik/pyminer