# Has anyone tried mining with visitors' computers

Tags: webminer

Some sites like http://www.bitcoinplus.com/generate allow that.

But can javascript take advantage of GPU?

Comment: When I clicked your link, it told me: "It looks like you don't have Java installed. Please install java at Java.com".  So it's probably Java that would need to access the GPU, not Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at [this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/1520/323) about web miners.

In general, web miners use JavaScript and [WebCL](http://webcl.nokiaresearch.com/) in order to perform operations on the GPU.

However, it might not be as profitable as you think. Considering that most people have very poor GPUs. At the moment if you'd have someone with a decent 200MHash/s card on your website for 24h, you'd basically earn [3 cents](http://tpbitcalc.appspot.com/?difficulty=1583177.8474&hashrate=200.00&exchangerate=6.65&bitcoinsperblock=50.00&rigcost=500.00&powerconsumption=200.00&powercost=0.10&investmentperiod=355). You can check how much you could earn by visiting [my calculator](http://tpbitcalc.appspot.com). All in all, you're better with ads.

Comment: An important thing to add is that Ads do not (or at least less) disturb your customers. I would freak out if a webpage I visit starts using 100% of my GPU to mine for his own profit.

Comment: @StevenRoose in fact, at least one person on the StackExchange network alone [already has](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30005/java-problem-nearly-looks-like-a-virus)